# pysnmp getcmd timeout not worked

Tags: pysnmp

if i use one CommandGenerator to request same ip twice, first time the timeout is 0, second time the timeout is 60,    all result is "No SNMP response received before timeout", seems the second time's timeout not worked.
create CommandGenerator every time or request different ip will get correct result.
I am sure that timeout has passed to UdpTransportTarget, below is my part code:

```
 _cmdgen = cmdgen.CommandGenerator()
        import time
        try:
            #a = get_cmdgen()
            start_time = time.time()
            worker = SNMP(
                            "1.1.1.",
                            "public",
                            logger=logging,
                            port=161,
                            timeout=0,
                            retries=0,
                            device_info=device_info,
                            model_version=1
                            )

            output = worker.bulk_get(_cmdgen,["1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0"])
            print output
        except Exception as e:
            print str(e)
        finally:
            endtime = time.time()
            print (endtime-start_time)

        try:
            #a = get_cmdgen()
            start_time = time.time()
            worker1 = SNMP(
                "1.1.1.1",
                "public",
                logger=logging,
                port=161,
                timeout=60,
                retries=0,
                device_info=device_info,
                model_version=1
            )
            output = worker1.bulk_get(_cmdgen,["1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0"])
            print output
        except Exception as e:
            print str(e)
        finally:
            endtime1 = time.time()
            print (endtime1-start_time)
```

Comment: Looking at pysnmp code, this behaviour seems like a bug [in transport address caching](https://github.com/etingof/pysnmp/blob/master/pysnmp/hlapi/v3arch/lcd.py#L95).

Comment: @ilya-etingof  Great thanks, has sloved by clear cache. _cmdgen.snmpEngine.cache = {}

Comment: The fix has been [committed](https://github.com/etingof/pysnmp/tree/release-4.4.7). I wonder if you could try it out and cycle back in case of further issues. Thanks!